# Null terminator not getting added at end of initializer in case of unsigned char[]!

Tags: c, char

I have the following four lines of code:

```
unsigned char key[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
unsigned char iv[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
printf("key = %s length = %d\n",key, strlen((char *)key));
printf("iv = %s length = %d\n",iv, strlen((char *)iv));
```

With the initializer i expect a NULL character to be appended at the end of both the variables key and iv, so i expect the length for both to be 16, but the output i get when i compile and run this code is as shown below:

key = (32 binary characters) length = 32

iv = (16 binary characters) length = 16

But as we can see, the length of iv is 16 as expected, but the length of iv is greater than 16. Not sure why the null terminator was not added in case of key. Can someone please indicate if the null terminator is added by default or not.

Comment: Using an initialiser doesn't automatically null terminate a `char` array, even when the size is worked out automatically.  The null terminator is only included with the string literal form of initialiser.  (though if you explicitly specify an array size larger than the number of elements in the initialiser, it will zero the unspecified ones).

Comment: Also, `strlen()` doesn't give the size of the array... only the position of the null terminator.  Using it here gives undefined behaviour since the arrays don't contain one (though it may have seemed to find one outside the array bounds).

Comment: Basically, `"abcd"` is equivalent to `{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '\0' }`... but an initialiser list without a null character does not add one.

Comment: @Dmitri Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question: This type of initialization does not append the NULL Terminator at the end of the char array. You can for example look at the debug output from lldb:

[image]

[image]

As already mentioned strlen() is looking for the position of the NULL Terminator and as he can not find one, he reads into not allocated memory, which is undefinied behaviour

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if we do char key[] = "abcd"; will NULL get appended at the end??